# Cant define SQL variable when using WITH statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

This sql is valid:

```
 WITH A AS
 (SELECT TOP 1000 * 
  FROM dbo.SomeTable)

 SELECT * FROM A
```

While this one gives an error(*Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DECLARE'*):

```
WITH A AS
(SELECT TOP 1000 * 
 FROM dbo.SomeTable)

 DECLARE @dt DATETIME 

 SET @dt = GETDATE()
 SELECT * FROM A

 PRINT DATEDIFF(SS,GETDATE(),@dt)
```

Why?

Comment: Common table expression (WITH) is only valid for one command (next). You can't declare variables or do anything between `WITH A (...)` declaration and `SELECT * FROM A`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just do

```
DECLARE @dt DATETIME;

SET @dt = GETDATE();

WITH A
     AS (SELECT TOP 1000 *
         FROM   dbo.SomeTable)
SELECT *
FROM   A;

PRINT DATEDIFF(SS, GETDATE(), @dt);
```

The only valid thing following a CTE definition is a single statement using it

Comment: No, I want to set the time after `A` was calculated

Comment: @Yosi - So move it after the `SELECT` then and before the `PRINT`.

Comment: @MartinSmith - thanks, I want to know how much time it takes to evaluate A, what you suggested doesn't solve this. but I got an answer to my original question :)

Comment: @Yosi - Well your use case seems based on a fundamental misunderstanding of how CTEs actually work. They are just inlined into the following query. They aren't materialised up front and evaluated in advance.

Comment: @MartinSmith - Taking back my downvote, can you please edit it so I can do that?

Comment: Is it true that you can define several other common table expressions after the first one regardless of whether they reference the first one or not? e.g ``;with a as (select * from t), b as (select * from tt) select * from a,b``

Comment: @axrwkr - Yes you can chain multiple together and SQL Server just validates that you reference at least one of them. `WITH T1 AS(SELECT * FROM spt_monitor), T2 AS(SELECT * FROM spt_values) SELECT * FROM T1` works fine for example.

Answer (score 2):

A CTE must be followed by a single SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement that references some or all the CTE columns. A CTE can also be specified in a CREATE VIEW statement as part of the defining SELECT statement of the view.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @dt DATETIME 

SET @dt = GETDATE()

WITH A AS
(SELECT TOP 1000 * 
FROM dbo.SomeTable)

SELECT * FROM A

PRINT DATEDIFF(SS,@dt,GETDATE())
```

This works fine for me, swap places of @dt and GETDATE() to get positive changes of seconds.
SET @dt before the select to get the calculations correctly.